# Unable to obtain new db connections in core java application after manually closing DB connections

Tags: java, postgresql

I have a core Java maven based application where I am using postgresql. I manually closed all the DB connections from PGAdmin. Now, if i try to obtain a new connection I am unable to do so until I restart the application.

Below is my Context.xml

```
<Resource
    name="jdbc/connection"
    auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="10000"
    maxIdle="100"
    maxWait="100000"
    MaxConnections="200"
    removeAbandoned="true"
    removeAbandonedTimeout="500"
    defaultAutoCommit="true"
    factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
    username="<username>"
    password="<pass>"
    driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
    ssl="require"
    url="<host>" />
```

Could you please help out. Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you find this file? How did you use it? Looks like you have a connections leaks.

Comment: This is the Context.xml file, present in the WebContent/META-INF folder.

Comment: As for using it we are creating a DataSource from the file and using the same to get the connections.

Comment: Why did you manually close the connections? What happens when you "try to obtain a new connection"?

Comment: What are you saying? How did you create a data source. How did you get connections from data source? You should post a code.